# ListAdapter Values are not displayed

Tags: android, listview, listadapter, getview

I need to dispaly my values in list view and i need to perform a click for particular textview alone in the list view

I have tried like this

```
ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                                ViewAppoinmentScreen.this, medicationlist,
                                R.layout.appoinmentlist, new String[] {
                                        "clinic_name", "id", "app_type",
                                        "app_date", "app_time", "app_desc" },
                                new int[] { R.id.name, R.id.app_id,
                                        R.id.app_type, R.id.date, R.id.time,
                                        R.id.comments }){

                            @Override
                            public View getView (int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                                LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                                View rowView = mInflater.inflate(
                                        R.layout.appoinmentlist, parent, false);
                                ImageView del = (ImageView) rowView
                                  .findViewById(R.id.imageView3);
                                del.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(View v) {
                                        String id = ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.app_id))
                                                .getText().toString();
                                        Toast.makeText(ViewAppoinmentScreen.this, " Clicked Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                        System.out.println("deleted action"+id);


                                    }
                                });

                                return rowView;
                            }

                        };

                        med_list.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Getview method is working i can able to see the toast message but i cant able to see the values in my listview. Values are not set to adapter. 
What mistake i have done i don't know ?Please help me.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Check if `medicationlist` is null or not

Comment: no `medicationlist` is  not null

Comment: Is d imageview visible? The toast is displayed when you click del...so d row is inflatd

Comment: yes its visible, when i click i can see the toast , but can't see the textfield values in the list shows empty

Comment: use custom listview with a base adapter class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved my issuse by replace the `getView` by something like this

```
@Override
                            public View getView (int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
                            {
                                View v = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

                                ImageView del = (ImageView) v
                                          .findViewById(R.id.imageView3);
                                del.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(View arg0) {
                                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                        Toast.makeText(ViewAppoinmentScreen.this,"Deleted",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    }
                                });
                                return v;
                            }
```

Now its fine.